# Received ValidationException when update DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I created one item in my dynamodb and then my nodejs lambda function will keep updating access_token value inside this item. Below is the schema

```
{
  "service": {
    "S": "perform"
  },
  "access_token": {
    "S": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Below are the dynamodb parameters that I will send to dynamodb update function

```
{
    "TableName": "Access-Token",
    "Key": {
        "service": "perform"
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "set access_token = :token",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":token": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
}
```

But when I run the lambda function i received below error. Need help and guide on this

> ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: What is your primary key for the table (partition key / sort key)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that you are trying to insert a record which does not have all the key elements.

If your primary key is a combination of the partition/hash key and range/sort key, you need to include both in your Key attribute in the update or put parameters.

Looks like the key `service` is your **Partition key** and the key `access_token` is your **Sort key**.

To do a update you need to send both keys:

```
"Key": {
    "service": "perform",
    "access_token": "token"
}
```

In this way, if try to update the `access_token` you will not be able because the  `access_token` attribute is part of the key.

If you want to update the `access_token` you will need to create another table without/or with a different sort key, and use the `access_token` as atribute.